# Exporting Oracle tables with foreign key relations to MC Access

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g

We have a requirement wherein client needs data of approx 25 tables in access with foreign key relationship.

As of now the database is in Oracle. Client is non technical and is comfortable with data in Access tables for his quick reference.

We have tried exporting Oracle tables with relations using DB Converter tool but found some limitation in exporting data using trial version.

Please suggest the ways with which we can export table data and foreign key from Oracle to Access for approx 25 tables,